# Can steady currents be time dependent?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electrostatics/magnetostatics applies when charge density doesn't vary with time, which by the continuity equation implies div J = 0.

But do steady currents also require the current density J to not vary with time?

Comment: that is the definition of steady

Comment: In a literal sense that's true. But some authors omit this point and just mention that J is divergenceless, so it was bothering me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $\frac{d \rho}{dt}=0$ alone is not sufficient to ensure that $\frac{d \vec{J}}{dt}=0$. Since $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$ we have

$\displaystyle\frac{d\vec{J}}{dt} = \frac {d\rho}{dt} \vec{v} + \rho \frac {d\vec{v}}{dt}$

Even if $\frac {d\rho}{dt}=0$, a non-zero $\frac {d\vec{v}}{dt}$ will produce a non-zero $\frac{d\vec{J}}{dt}$.

For example, you could have charge density $\rho$ that is constant in time and space but which oscillates backwards and forwards with velocity $v = \sin(\omega t) \vec{x}$, in which case $\vec{J} = \rho\sin(\omega t) \vec{x}$ and $\frac{d \vec{J}}{dt} = \rho \omega \sin(\omega t) \vec{x}$.

Comment: So is the $\frac{d \rho}{dt}=0$ condition really necessary when just considering magnetostatics?